# Passing the parameters to assembly file from POM.xml

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Can we pass the parameter from POM to assembly file. I want to use that parameter inside a file which will be packaged by the assembly file itself.
I know we can create profiles in assembly but that will not solve my problem.

from POM ---->pass the parameter in assembly file--> use that parameter in abc.sh file which is packaged  by assembly file.

Comment: well shell scripts(.sh) can use parameters passed. Could you elaborate on the type of assembly you mean to use here.

Comment: You can set properties which can be used during filtering in assembly...